# Verifying arguments passed to static method with Mockito and PowerMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, static-methods, powermockito

I'm trying to test a void method though verifying the arguments it passes to a static method when it calls it. The static method is in charge of persisting those arguments.

```
class ProxyHandler {
  public void process(String str) {
    // parse the str and populate x, y, z
    PersistManager.proxy(x, y, z); 
  }
}
```

PersistManager below contains the static method that I'm trying to capture the arguments it receives.

```
class PersistManager {
  public static void proxy(String x, String y, String z) {
    // persist the x, y, z
  }
}
```

And finally my test class, testing ProxyHandler:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(PersistManager.class)
public class TestProxyHandler() {
   private ProxyHandler handler;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
     handler = new ProxyHandler();
   }

   @Test
   public void testProxy() {
     PowerMockito.mockStatic(PersistManager.class);
     ArgumentCaptor<String> arg1 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
     ArgumentCaptor<String> arg2 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
     ArgumentCaptor<String> arg3 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

     handler.process("a long string");
     PowerMockito.verifyStatic(PersistManager.class, times(1));
     PersistManager.proxy(arg1.capture(), arg2.capture(), arg3.capture());
     assertEquals("x", arg1.getValue());
   }
}
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
Wanted but not invoked PersistManager.proxy(
    null,
    null,
    null
);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I also noticed that if I change the value of times(1) to any other value, the verifyStatic still passes. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `verifyStatic` shouldn't need a times argument - it looks like the default of that is 1 time.  I also see that `arg2,capture()` is done with a comma - I'm guessing that was a typo when posting ?  I'm not overly familiar with PowerMockito, though, so I'm not totally sure on answering that.

Comment: You're correct about the ",". Fixed. I know about the default times being 1 but I was trying to stress that even if I pass 2, 3 to that, it'd still pass.

Comment: Just a comment that I ended up using JMockit since I never managed to get this to work. For anyone having the same issue, I strongly recommend using JMockit for testing legacy code such as above.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @Sam, I just found my answer again because it was upvoted. I noticed that you never gave any feedback and never accepted my answer in order to close the question. Please be so kind as to accept & upvote, if the answer is correct. Otherwise, please explain what you think it wrong with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to answer this question so late but I just found it by chance because I was investigating something else with Powermockito. I replicated your situation as follows (sorry, I don't like the default package):

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q49946922;

class PersistManager {
  public static void proxy(String x, String y, String z) {
    System.out.printf("Persisting %s, %s, %s%n", x, y, z);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q49946922;

public class ProxyHandler {
  public void process(String str) {
    String[] params = str.split(" ");
    PersistManager.proxy(params[0], params[1], params[2]);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q49946922;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(PersistManager.class)
public class ProxyHandlerTest {
  private ProxyHandler handler;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    handler = new ProxyHandler();
  }

  @Test
  public void testProxy() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(PersistManager.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<String> arg1 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<String> arg2 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<String> arg3 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

    handler.process("a long string");
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(PersistManager.class, times(1));
    PersistManager.proxy(arg1.capture(), arg2.capture(), arg3.capture());
    assertEquals("a", arg1.getValue());
    assertEquals("long", arg2.getValue());
    assertEquals("string", arg3.getValue());
  }
}
```

This works flawlessly. You probably have done something wrong or there is a problem in the code you didn't show. There is no need to switch to JMockit.

BTW, I used PowerMock 2.0.2, Mockito 2.23.0, JUnit 4.12, Java 8.